# Why acc of char-level cnn for text classification stay unchanged

Tags: nlp, keras, conv-neural-network

**I misused binary cross-entropy for softmax, changed to categorical cross-entropy. And did some reviewing about details of the problem below in my own answer**

---

I am trying to using open source data: sogou_news_csv(converted to pinyin using *jieba* from for text classification following https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01710 "Text understanding from scratch" by Xiang Zhang and Yann LeCun. (mainly follow the idea of using character level CNN, but the structure proposed in the paper).

I did the preprocessing by using one-hot encoding according to a *alphabet collection* and filling all those not in the *alphabet collection* with 0s.
As a result, I got the training data with the shape of (450000, 1000, 70),(data_size, sequence_length, alphabet_size).

Then I feed the data into a cnn structure following http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/.

**Problem is** 
**During the training, the loss and acc merely change, I tried preprocessing again for the data, and `tried different learning rate settings`, but not helpful, So what went wrong?**

Below is one-hot encoding:

```
import numpy as np

all_letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-,;.!?:'\"/\\|_@#$%^&*~`+-=<>()[]{}\n"
n_letters = len(all_letters)

def letterToIndex(letter):
    """
    'c' -> 2
    """
    return all_letters.find(letter)


def sets2tensors(clean_train, n_letters=n_letters, MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH=1000):
    """
    From lists of cleaned passages to np.array with shape(len(train), 
        max_sequence_length, len(dict))
    Arg: 
        obviously
    """
    m = len(clean_train)
    x_data = np.zeros((m, MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, n_letters))
    for ix in range(m):
        for no, letter in enumerate(clean_train[ix]):
            if no >= 1000:
                break
            letter_index = letterToIndex(letter)
            if letter != -1:
                x_data[ix][no][letter_index]  = 1
            else:
                continue            
    return x_data
```

This is the Model:

```
num_classes = 5
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation, GlobalMaxPool1D, Merge, concatenate, Conv1D, Dense, Dropout
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.optimizers import SGD
submodels = []
for kw in (3, 4, 5):    # kernel sizes
    submodel = Sequential()
    submodel.add(Conv1D(32,
                        kw,
                        padding='valid',
                        activation='relu',
                        strides=1, input_shape=(1000, n_letters)))
    submodel.add(GlobalMaxPool1D())
    submodels.append(submodel)
big_model = Sequential()
big_model.add(Merge(submodels, mode="concat"))
big_model.add(Dense(64))
big_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
big_model.add(Activation('relu'))
big_model.add(Dense(num_classes))
big_model.add(Activation('softmax'))
print('Compiling model')
opt = SGD(lr=1e-6)  # tried different learning rate from 1e-6 to 1e-1
# changed from binary crossentropy to categorical_crossentropy
big_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                  optimizer=opt,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Some results

```
Train on 5000 samples, validate on 5000 samples
Epoch 1/5
5000/5000 [==============================] - 54s - loss: 0.5198 - acc: 0.7960 - val_loss: 0.5001 - val_acc: 0.8000
Epoch 2/5
5000/5000 [==============================] - 56s - loss: 0.5172 - acc: 0.7959 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_acc: 0.8000
Epoch 3/5
5000/5000 [==============================] - 56s - loss: 0.5198 - acc: 0.7965 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_acc: 0.8000
Epoch 4/5
5000/5000 [==============================] - 57s - loss: 0.5222 - acc: 0.7950 - val_loss: 0.4999 - val_acc: 0.8000
Epoch 5/5
5000/5000 [==============================] - 59s - loss: 0.5179 - acc: 0.7960 - val_loss: 0.4999 - val_acc: 0.8000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem is I accidentally used binary cross-entropy(that I used for another dataset) with softmax, which should be categorical cross-entropy. Initially, I figured it is a stupid bug since I didn't carefully check the code and logic.

But then I found I don't really understand what is going on here, I mean, I know the difference between binary cross-entropy and categorical cross-entropy, but I don't really understand the details why softmax and categorical cross-entropy can't be chained together.

Luckily, I found a very nice explanation here(did not expect anyone would actually ask or answer this question)

https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/39bo7k/can_softmax_be_used_with_cross_entropy/#cs2b4jx

Basically what it is saying is that in binary cross-entropy case, the loss function is **treating two different values of a single bit as two different class**: like 1 for A and 0 for B, despite that with categorical cross-entropy case, the loss function is taking a vector like [0,0,0,1,0] a label, in which the value of a bit stands for the confidence or probability for the corresponding training example being that particular class.

With description above, when we apply binary cross-entropy to softmax, we are misusing the definition of what **one bit** means in that setting, thus make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have set SGD optimizer to 0.000001 (opt = SGD(lr=1e-6))

The default learning rate for SGD is 0.01

keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.0, decay=0.0, nesterov=False)

I suspect that 1e-6 is to small, try increase it and/or try a different optimizer

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already changed the learning rate from 1e-1 to 1e-6 gradually by a factor of 10, and also tried adam, but did not help

Comment: I actually found my loss function is wrong, it should be categorical_crossentropy since its a muti-class problem...